# Javascript variable not refreshing in Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have just written my first app in phonegap that simply replaces a text string on the screen each time you activate a link.

The original string stays where it is and the new string is written over the top. If you then activate the link again the second string is replaced with a new one but still over the top of the first string.

I have tried clearing the variable to fix this but no luck.

Is this a platform limitation or am i doing something wrong?

## Code is below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="newIdea()">
<h1 class="h1">First Love</h1>
<p>Have you ever? </p>
<h3><div id="ideaDiv">Nothing</div></h3>
<a href="#" id="ideaLink">Let's Do it</a>
<a href="#" onclick="newIdea();">No Thanks</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ideas=new Array(); // regular array (add an optional integer
ideas[0]="Kissed someone in the rain";       // argument to control array's size)
ideas[1]="Eaten peking duck";
ideas[2]="Stood naked in the open";

function newIdea(){
var idea = "";
var idea = ideas[Math.floor(Math.random()*ideas.length)];
var ideaSpace = document.getElementById("ideaDiv");
ideaSpace.innerHTML=idea;
var ideaLink=document.getElementById("ideaLink");
var linkCreate="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=" + idea + "&dates=20120101/20120102&details=&location=&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:";
ideaLink.href=linkCreate;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with phonegap, but in the past I found some problems trying to set `innerHTML` in xhtml documents, it don't check if the string you are using causes the document to still a valid xml and just throws an error, to achieve the same effect try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="newIdea()">
<h1 class="h1">First Love</h1>
<p>Have you ever? </p>
<h3><div id="ideaDiv">Nothing</div></h3>
<a href="#" id="ideaLink">Let's Do it</a>
<a href="#" onclick="newIdea();">No Thanks</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ideas=new Array(); // regular array (add an optional integer
ideas[0]="Kissed someone in the rain";       // argument to control array's size)
ideas[1]="Eaten peking duck";
ideas[2]="Stood naked in the open";

function newIdea(){
var idea = "";
var idea = ideas[Math.floor(Math.random()*ideas.length)];
var ideaSpace = document.getElementById("ideaDiv");
//ideaSpace.innerHTML=idea;
ideaSpace.removeChild(ideaSpace.firstChild);
ideaSpace.appendChild(document.createTextNode(idea));
var ideaLink=document.getElementById("ideaLink");
var linkCreate="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=" + idea + "&dates=20120101/20120102&details=&location=&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:";
ideaLink.href=linkCreate;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```